# making router for parsing javascript request through php

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess

I have seen this request

```
https://somesite.com/path/script.js?shop=xyz.com
https://somesite.com/path/script.js?shop=abc.com
```

the output for both requests are different
earlier I was thinking that .js file cant be treated like php and dynamic data cant be passed but I was wrong and some expert advised that its router which is passing these data and according to shop name they are serving.

I have php  apache+ nginx server

can anyone tell how we can make this work. don't want to go with Nodejs as it won't allow to pass php code.

just for test i want to call above links and print this.

```
hi i am shop xyz

or hi i am shop abc
```

on respective calls.

can anyone share some details guidelines how to make router. any link any guide any advise will solv the purpose.

I have never dealth with such javascript ant it is damm easy in php extension but want to learn in javascript.

Comment: If you want to setup up a full-fleged PHP routing system, then this is way too broad of a question. In that case, please start by doing some proper research yourself - this is not a new topic, so you should be able to find explanations on how this generally works, tutorials etc. enough.

Comment: @04FS i searched lot. everywhere i am getting index.php routing. i want js routing

Comment: […] or your could make it `/path/script.php` to begin with (in that case, your PHP script just needs to output an appropriate Content-Type header first, so that the client knows the response is supposed to be Javascript.)

Comment: i cant pass script.php that is the problem otherwise php explode will do all and as u said content header javascript then it will print javascript

Comment: Absolutely unclear what you are even trying to say with that.

Comment: @04FS  sorry. i want to serve different content based on shop parameter but the request is from script.js so i am unable to do as its .js file

Comment: That why I said, you can rewrite these specific requests to a PHP file internally then, using mod_rewrite.